# Как вывести объект из вложенного массива?

Tags: javascript, json

Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть 5 объектов, выведенных из массива. В каждом из этих объектов имеется поле `conversation`, которое включает в себя также массив объектов. С помощью данного кода я пытаюсь вывести на страницу поле `text`, которое находится в каждом из объектов поля conversation, однако не получается это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю ошибку, типа `element is not iterable`, `obj is not iterable`. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо вам большое

```
fetch("./messages.json")
.then(response => {return response.json()})
.then(data => {
    for (let i = 42; i < 47; i++) {
        let element = data[i];
        console.log(element)
        for (const obj of element) {

        }
    }
})

fetch("./messages.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    for (let i = 42; i < 47; i++) {
        for (let obj in Object.values(data[i].conversation)) {
            for (let key of obj) {
                for (let conv in key) {
                    console.log(conv.text);
                }
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Небольшой пример: есть главный массив, в котором есть поле `conversation`, в котором содержатся объекты, в которых есть поле `text`. Именно это поле я пытаюсь вывести на html страницу

```
let mainArray = [ {participants: ['one', 'two'], conservation: [
        {sender: 'person1', text: "simple_text1"},
        {sender: 'person2', text: "simple_text2"},
        {sender: 'person3', text: "simple_text3"}]}
]
```

Comment: ну `d` у тебя объект. у объекта нет for..of, только for...in  или Object.entries/keys/values

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо, но оно не выводит то что нужно, дале если изменить

Comment: смотря как применять. без тестовых данных **не в виде скрина**  и том, **как именно применяешь другие варианты** говорить не о чем

Comment: и вообще судя по скрину полагаю достаточно одного цикла и `console.log(d)`

Comment: какие дополнительные данные еще представить?

Comment: вместо скринов -  данные текстом (хотя бы срез в 5 элементов). И написать какой ожидаемый результат нужен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, немного изменил вопрос, добавил пример

Answer (score 1):

Это обычный цикл по массиву:

```js
let mainArray = [{ participants: ['one1', 'two1'],conservation: [{ sender: 'person1', text: "simple_text1" },{ sender: 'person2', text: "simple_text21" },{ sender: 'person3', text: "simple_text31" }]},
                  {participants: ['one2', 'two2'],conservation: [{ sender: 'person1', text: "simple_text1" },{ sender: 'person22', text: "simple_text2" },{ sender: 'person3', text: "simple_text23" }]},
                  { participants: ['one3', 'two3'],conservation: [{ sender: 'person1', text: "simple_text1" },{ sender: 'person2', text: "simple_text23" },{ sender: 'person3', text: "simple_text33" }]},
                  { participants: ['one4', 'two4'],conservation: [{ sender: 'person1', text: "simple_text1" },{ sender: 'person2', text: "simple_text24" },{ sender: 'person3', text: "simple_text34" }]}
];

for (let i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
  for (let conservation of mainArray[i].conservation) {
    //console.log(conservation, '.........text: ', conservation.text);
    document.write(conservation.text + ' ');
    } 
    
  document.write('</br></br> ');
}
```

В данном случае `mainArray[0]` потому что на входе объект в массиве..... если бы не было первых квадратных скобок, от было бы просто `mainArray.conservation`

Comment: Да, большое спасибо за помощь, но как я и говорил, что я получаю данные из файла, поэтому для этого использую `fetch`. Использую я цикл для того, чтобы вывести только объекты с 42 по 47. А на страницу вывести мне нужно каждое поле `text`, находящееся внутри вложенных объектов, которые находятся в массиве поля `conversation` как на картинке. Извините, что так запутано. Пожалуйста, можете помочь с этим?

Comment: Переделал код - в этом суть? цикл в цикле? Или нужно с конкретного места до конкретного индекса вывести? Пока не уловил суть проблемы если честно

Comment: Я добавил пояснения под кодом, потому что в комментарии не влезает

Comment: @Halland заменил for...of на обычный for.

Comment: Да, это сработало) Спасибо большое. Сейчас добавлю ответ)))

Answer (score 0):

`mainArray` – массив, который я уже разобрал на картинке, из 5 объектов. `mainArray` у меня находится в отдельном файле `messages.json`, поэтому я использую функцию `fetch`. В общем, у меня объектов есть 87, однако мне нужно только определенные, поэтому с помощью цикла я выбрал, какие мне нужно (между 42 и 47). У каждого объекта на картинке и на примере моем есть поле `conversation`, которое внутри себя имеет 100 вложенных объектов. Каждый из этих 100 объектов имеет поле `text`, так же как и на моем примере. Моя цель состоит в том, чтобы вывести поле `text` на страницу мою. Здесь проблема во вложенности. Я просто пытался объяснить картинку своим примером, где находится поле `text`, которое нужно вывести.

Поэтому, по примеру из массива в коде, а также моем условии задания, код решения выглядит так

```
fetch("./messages.json")
.then(response => {return response.json()})
.then(data => {
    for (let i = 42; i < 47; i++) {
        for (let conversation of data[i].conversation) {
            document.write(`<div>${conversation.text}</div>`)
        }
    }
})
```